# Nested foreach Loops on a Webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am selecting the following data from an SQL database table in my controller

```
            var fixtures = from f in _context.Fixtures
                       where f.MatchDate.Year == year &&
                       (gender.Contains( f.Gender )) &&
                       (type.Contains( f.MatchType )) &&
                       (team.Contains( f.TeamName ))
                       orderby f.TeamName, f.MatchDate
                       select f;

        return View( "DisplayLeagues", fixtures.ToList() );
```

and calling the `DisplayLeagues` view to display it. As you can see from the `orderby`, it contains more than one team. I want to display a separate table on the webpage for each team. My page declaration contains

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<RLSBCWebSite.Domain.Entities.Fixture>>"
```

as the declaration of the Model. To display the individual lines of the table, I have

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.AsEnumerable()) { %>
```

But how do I add a loop control based on the name of the team around the table as a whole? It doesn't seem possible to code

```
<% foreach (var team in Model.TeamName ....
```

Comment: I'm not sure what type Model.TeamName is. I'd assume that it is a string?

You need to add a list of teams to your model, and loop through this list.

Comment: @MartinMH: Model.TeamName is indeed a string. It does contain a list of teams. This can either be a single team or four different teams defined by '(team.Contains( f.TeamName ))'. It is then ordered by the teams, thus: 'orderby f.TeamName, f.MatchDate'. I then want to display a separate table in my view for each team in the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the outer loop, which produces a separate table for each team, I used the following

```
<% foreach (var teamName in Model.AsEnumerable().GroupBy( r => r.TeamName )) {
```

For the inner loop, which produces the individual matches for each team, I used

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.AsEnumerable().Where(item => item.TeamName == teamName.Key.ToString())) {
```

This works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
group g by f.TeamName into tmp
select new {TeamName  = f.Key, Fixtures = tmp.ToList() }
```

this will give you one group per team, i.e.

```
foreach(var grp in query) {
    Console.WriteLine(grp.TeamName);
    foreach(var fixture in grp.Fixtures) {
       // write fixture details
    }
}
```

Note that this changes each item to an `IGrouping<string, List<Fixture>>`, and note that `ToLookup` will do something very similar if that is easier.

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply. I came up with something similar this morning when I was lying in bed deciding whether to get up or not.